# Warning: ONNX Preprocess - Removing mutation on block inputs. This changes graph semantics

Tags: pytorch, onnx, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-geometric, torchscript

using **pytorch_lightning** and **pytorch-geometric** env to export a onnx model, occur this problem, and the program exists. But export a torchscript model is good.

origin input datatype is only a dict, I just try to replace the input datatype from dict to tuple, the same error, and didn't find any related solutions to sovle it.

when export a torchscript is good.